# Windows batch commands to get user info

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to retrieve user information using batch. What I need is information for the groups the user belongs to and for the security settings for this user. I was not able to find any commands that would help me to achieve that. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse outputs from `net user /domain <user>` or `gpresult /r` commands.